# violation of Haskell indentation rules for if-then-else

Tags: haskell

According to the [Haskell indentation rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation), "*Code which is part of some expression should be indented further in than the beginning of that expression*". However, I found the following example, which seems to violate the rule above, compiles without any error or warning:

```
someFunction :: Bool -> Int -> Int -> Int
someFunction condition a b = if condition
then a - b
      else a + b
```

Here I am defining a function `someFunction`, its body is an `if-then-else` block. According to the indentation rule, the `then` block is a part of the same expression in the first line, so it should be indented further than its previous line. Yet in my example, the second line `then` starts at the same column as the first line, and this example compiles.

I am not sure what is going on here. I am working with GHC version 8.0.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure this is an artifact of a [deliberate GHC variation on the indentation rule](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/DoAndIfThenElse). Nice catch!

GHC reads this

```
foo = do
  item
  if a
  then b
  else c
  item
```

as

```
foo = do {
  item ;
  if a ;
  then b ;
  else c ;
  item }
```

which should trigger a parse error.

However, this was so common that at a certain point the GHC devs decided to allow for an optional `;` before `then` and `else`. This change to the `if` grammar makes the code compile.

This means that `if` became "special", in that it does not have to indented more, but only as much as the previous item. In the code posted in the question, `then` is indented as much as the previous item, so there's an implicit `;` before it, and that makes the code compile.

I would still try to avoid this "style", though, since it's quirky.

(Personally, I wouldn't have added this special case to GHC. But it's not a big deal, anyway.)

I now noticed that the Wikibook mentions this variant as a "proposal" for a future version of Haskell. This is a bit outdated now, and has been implemented in GHC since then.

Comment: In imperative code I can only stand `if cond then\n  foo\nelse\n  bar` style aesthetic, the others drive me nuts. Thanks GHC dudes.